# ELSIF V/S ELSE IF IN ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

what is difference between those two.

```
elsif

else if
```

while both are executing fine with no errors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ELSIF does not need a matching END IF. If the condition for the 1st IF is not satisfied, then the ELSIF condition is checked.

ELSE IF will need a matching END IF, because a new IF block is started.

**References**:

[PL/SQL Control Statements on Oracle® Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS004)

Comment: Thanks.  I really dont like Oracle for this nonsense right now.

Answer (score 13):

An `IF` statement in PL/SQL is structured as

```
IF <<some condition>>
THEN
  <<do something>>
ELSIF <<another condition>>
THEN
  <<do something else>>
ELSE
  <<do a third thing>>
END IF;
```

where both the `ELSIF` and the `ELSE` are optional.  If you are seeing an `ELSE IF`, that indicates that someone is creating a nested `IF` statement (with a nested `END IF`) in an `ELSE` block.  That is

```
IF <<some condition>>
THEN
  <<do something>>
ELSE
  IF <<another condition>>
  THEN
    <<do something else>>
  END IF;
END IF;
```

You can, if you so desire, nest PL/SQL blocks as deeply as you'd like.  Generally, though, your code will be cleaner if you don't nest things more than necessary.  Unless there is a compelling reason here to create a nested `IF` statement, you're much more likely to produce readable code using a single `IF` statement with one or more `ELSIF` blocks (or, even better, a `CASE`).  Plus, that way you're not trying to count up all the `END IF` statements you need to close all the nested `IF` statements.

Comment: Where is the 3rd thing in expanded block?